# How can I unit test my controller in Laravel 5?

Tags: unit-testing, laravel, phpunit, laravel-5

I have the folowing controller, how to do unit test for destroy function?

```
/**
     * Delete Bank by Id
     *
     * @param int $id
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $this->bankService->delete($this->bankService->findById($id, new ApiRequest()));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You provided very less information. Here is a generic test:

```php
class BanksControllerTest extends TestCase
{
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;

    public function testDeleteById()
    {
        $user = App\User::findOrFail(1); // The user required to access the controller, if any
        $id = 1; // The id of the bank you want to delete
        $page = route('banks.destroy', $id); // The URL of the controller
        $table = 'banks'; // The table that contains the banks

        $this->actingAs($user)->visit($page)->notSeeInDatabase($table, ['id' => $id]);
    }
}
```

Obviously you'll need to adapt it for your scenario